# How to prevent APEX code from showing when viewing the page source?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a Visual Force and Apex code page in my sandbox,

And I will deploy the page into my organization and then make the page live as a website,

In Firefox browser, when you right click the page and choose view source,

The whole apex code is shown,

How do I prevent that?

Comment: Do you have Development Mode turned on? Because it normally just shows the HTML and not the Apex.

Comment: yes i do, so you are saying that when the page is deployed and its a live website, only the HTML will show, is that correct?

Comment: Right, because development mode shows the source code so you can make changes right there on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be caused by viewing the Visualforce page with Development Mode turned on. When this is active, the page has an iFrame with the source code so you can directly make changes, hence seeing the code in the HTML source. If you view the page with Development Mode turned off you should just see the regular HTML.

Answer (score 2):

The Apex Code won't be shown when viewing it through Sites. Only an internal user with sufficient privileges would see this code.

Answer (score 0):

The APEX code--if properly formatted--will never be shown.  The APEX code is parsed, processed, and then HTML is output to the browser.  Are you sure all of your APEX is properly wrapped in `<apex:xyz></apex:xyz>` tags?

Comment: I think Mike Chale abdsfdcfox just answered my questioned, thanks for your response